# Google Script - Forms: Working programatically with upload fields: how to get multiple links? How to deal with 'undefined' when nothing is uploaded?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm running into two issues when working with upload fields in google script. I will try to describe my issue as best as I can.

I have a form, with a trigger set for when its sent. This trigger calls a main function that in return calls some other functions.

One of the subfunctions creates a doc, then sets its link on a specific sheet.

The main function gets the item responses object in the following line:

```
var responses = e.response.getItemResponses();
```

Then, this object is passed to the Doc function as an argument:

```
generateBriefingPDF(classID, briefingSheet, responses, timestamp);
```

ClassID is a simple integer property, briefingSheet is the destination sheet and timestamp I get from:

```
var timestamp = e.response.getTimestamp();
```

Inside the generateBriefingPDF script, I get the responses and assign them to easier-to-read variables like so:

```
var name = responses[0].getResponse();
var subject = responses[1].getResponse();
var content = responses[2].getResponse();
var level = responses[3].getResponse();
var uploads = responses[4].getResponse();
```

Then I [replace text 'variables'](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement) in a new doc copied with a template with the variables.

I also set them in the sheet.

The "uploads" var is the id of the file, so I convert it to the link using:

```
uploads = DriveApp.getFileById(uploads).getUrl();
```

**This works fine**. Except for the "uploads" variable, from the response[4], which is an upload field.
The following occurs:

- **When nothing is uploaded:** The variable is *undefined*, so it cannot run the property "getResponse". I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getResponse' of undefined` on the Stackdriver log. I have tried to check for undefined with the following lines, none worked:

  `if(uploads !== undefined)`
  `if(typeof uploads !== "undefined")`
- **One file is uploaded:** Everything works.
- **More than one file is uploaded:** I get an error when trying to get the file by the ID (of course): `Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp.`
  When I didn't have the line to convert the ID to the link, the IDs were separated by a comma in the doc file, but only the first one appeared in the sheet.

What can I do to solve those two issues?

Comment: I believe you are using Google Forms with onFormSubmit Trigger.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Cooper Yes. That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to modify your script for the cases that a file and/or multiple files are uploaded using Google Form.

#### Modification points:

From your script, I thought that your script might be the container-bound script of Google Form. And from `More than one file is uploaded`, I think that `uploads` of `var uploads = responses[4].getResponse()` is an array including the file IDs of uploaded files. In this case, `responses[4]` for each situation becomes as follows.

- When the file is not uploaded, `responses[4]` is `undefined`.

  - This has already been mentioned in your question.
- When a file and/or multiple files are uploaded, `responses[4]` is the object of ItemResponse and `responses[4].getResponse()` is an array including the file IDs of uploaded files.

  - When one file is uploaded, `var uploads = responses[4].getResponse()` is like `["###fileId###"]`. In this case, `DriveApp.getFileById(uploads)` works. I think that `uploads.toString()` might be used for this situation. But, when multiple files are uploaded, the file ID is not existing. By this, the error occurs.
  - About the issue in `More than one file is uploaded`, I thought that this is the reason of your issue.

I think that in order to achieve your goal, above situation can be used. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var uploads = responses[4].getResponse();
```

To:

```
var uploads = "";
if (responses[4]) {  // or if(uploads !== undefined) if(typeof uploads !== "undefined")
  uploads = responses[4].getResponse().map(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).getUrl()).join(",");
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, when one file is uploaded, `uploads` is one URL. For example, when 2 files are uploaded, `uploads` is a string value including 2 URLs like `URL1,URL2`. If you want to use it as an array, please modify to `uploads = responses[4].getResponse().map(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).getUrl())`.
- When no files are uploaded, `uploads` is `""`.

#### References:

- [Class FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response)
- [getResponse()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response#getResponse())
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the swift answer. Today I wasn't able to work on this, but tomorrow I'll try your solution. I think it's going to work.

Comment: @Set Thank you for replying. When my proposed answer was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Set Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.